# Getting Notification Request to complete before Send Notification fires

Tags: ios, swift, closures, uilocalnotification

I have been attempting to implement an instance of local notifications without much luck.  It seems that it tries to schedule the notification before the closure for the request is completed and therefore never gets scheduled correctly.

I have the two following methods constructed for the request and send:

```
func requestNotificationAuthorization(myDate: Date) {
       let authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptions.init(arrayLiteral: .alert, .badge, .sound)
       self.userNotificationCenter.requestAuthorization(options: authOptions) { (success, error) in
         if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
         }
       }
   }
   
   
   func sendNotification(myDate: Date) {
      let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
      content.title = "My Title"
      content.body = "Placeholder for data from Firebase"
      content.sound = .default
      
      let triggerDaily = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: myDate)
      let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDaily, repeats: true)
      let identifier = "LocalNotification"
      let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)

      userNotificationCenter.add(request, withCompletionHandler: { (error) in
           if let error = error {
               print("Error")
           }
       })
   }
```

The following are the calls for these methods:

```
         let newDate = formatter.date(from: myDate)
         self.requestNotificationAuthorization(myDate: newDate!)


         self.sendNotification(myDate: newDate!)
```

I'm not sure how to hold off with the sendNotification call until I'm sure that the requestNotification has been completed successfully.  If anyone is willing to provide some useful help with this, I would be most appreciative.

Comment: Basic `asynchrone` concept. In When you do `if let error = error {` inside `requestAuthorization(options:)` closure, there call `sendTheNotification` if granted.

Comment: Thanks Larme I thought I had tried that but either I didn't or didn't get it right the first time.  I'm good with it now.

Answer (score 0):

Larme got it right, if someone knows how to give him credit other my saying so here I would appreciate it.